# How to show currency of stock in Interactive Brokers

Tags: brokerage, broker, interactive-brokers

I am using Client Portal in Interactive Brokers. I can see the price for an instrument (stock or etf).

Where can I see the currency and prospectus/documents for the instruments?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that client portal doesn't have an option to add "Trading Currency" column in watchlist, but mobile application and Trading Workstation have this option.

Answer (score 0):

In the IBKR browser client portal.

- Portfolio.
- Select an asset.
- If you click on the `(i)` icon next to `Avg. Price` on the right, the currency is shown there.

Not ideal, but only a single click to see the currency.

[image: IBKR portfolio view]